# Duplicate rows in linq query

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I've got view `vw_AllNomenLost` in my database

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT ProducerName, NomenCode, SUM(ErrorCount) AS ErrorCount
FROM         dbo.NomenLost
GROUP BY ProducerName, NomenCode
ORDER BY ErrorCount DESC
```

and I added it to Entity Model.

I want to get top 10 rows by Producer and sorted by `ErrorCount`

```
db.vw_AllNomenLost.Where(a => a.ProducerName == producer).OrderByDescending(a => a.ErrorCount).Take(10);
```

In the debugger I get :

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Project1].[NomenCode] AS [NomenCode], 
    [Project1].[ProducerName] AS [ProducerName], 
    [Project1].[ErrorCount] AS [ErrorCount]
    FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ProducerName] AS [ProducerName], 
        [Extent1].[NomenCode] AS [NomenCode], 
        [Extent1].[ErrorCount] AS [ErrorCount]
        FROM (

    SELECT  
[vw_AllNomenLost].[ProducerName] AS [ProducerName], 

        [vw_AllNomenLost].[NomenCode] AS [NomenCode], 

        [vw_AllNomenLost].[ErrorCount] AS [ErrorCount]
    FROM [dbo].[vw_AllNomenLost] AS [vw_AllNomenLost]) AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ProducerName] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)


    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[ErrorCount] DESC
```

If I execute

```
SELECT     TOP (10) *
FROM        vw_AllNomenLost
where ProducerName = @producer
Order by ErrorCount desc
```

In Management Studio, I get a correct result. but my linq query returns some duplicate rows.

```
NomenCode   ErrorCount
31190RRAA00  11
31190RRAA00  11
31190RRAA00  11
31190RRAA00  11
```

How is it possible? I don't get it. What did I do wrong?  Thank you very much for reading and sorry for too long question.

Comment: Something doesn't add up here. The 2 queries you have shown are equivalent. So with the same input they must produce the same result. Are you executing both queries in SSMS with the same input?